# How to find a specific element inside the arrays which is surrounded by an object?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my contents of a document in the MongoDB. It has an object timestamps and a lot of arrays.

```
{
   "timestamps":{
      "1200":[
         "390.288",
         "390.818",
         "So"
      ],
      "1175":[
         "381.778",
         "382.248",
         "so"
      ],
      "1183":[
         "383.668",
         "383.928",
         "a"
      ],
      "1144":[
         "372.588",
         "372.718",
         "up"
      ],
      "1162":[
         "377.638",
         "377.928",
         "rial"
      ],
      "1218":[
         "395.798",
         "395.868",
         "me"
      ],
      "1145":[
         "372.718",
         "373.188",
         "So"
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I find the word `So` which is in `1200th` index and their timestamps which is in the 0th and the 1st index of that array?

Comment: So what is the expected output here ?

Comment: So, if I find `me` in the document I should able to get `"395.798", "395.868"`.

Comment: A few questions for the OP: are you asking about how to return only those values from mongoDB or how to parse the entire returned object from mongoDB to get those values? Also, 'So' matches more than one property in your example but you only reference the first, is the expected output only concerned with the first match? Finally, what have you are tried so far and where are you getting stuck with it? The first two questions might have been answered if you included your existing effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since your object keys are unknown you should start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator which can transform `timestamps` into an array of keys and values like below:

```
{
    "k" : "1144",
    "v" : [ "372.588", "372.718", "up"]
},
{
    "k" : "1145",
    "v" : [ "372.718", "373.188", "So"]
},
...
```

Then you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get only those documents where `v` contains your input phrase. Entire aggregation could look like this:

```
var input = "me";
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            foundElements: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$timestamps" },
                    as: "ts",
                    cond: { $ne: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$$ts.v", input ] }, -1 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            foundElements: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$foundElements",
                    as: "element",
                    in: { $slice: [ "$$element.v", 2 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) returns `-1` if array doesn't contain specified phrase. To reshape your results you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) with [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) which will take first two elements from your array (0th and 1st).

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ..., "foundElements" : [ [ "395.798", "395.868" ] ] }
```